# Install two incomptaible nvidia drivers at the same time in windows

Tags: windows-7, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a new compunter with a GTX 970 wich use Nvidia driver 353.06 and I want to use my old GTX 280 wich uses driver 341.44. The problem I've is that the drivers overwrite the other so I can only have one of them installed (and on of the cards running) at the same time. I had installed the drivers manually through windows device properties.

Each driver doesn't inlcude the others architecture so I can't use only the latest driver versions.

Can I install both drivers in any way? Something like install one, rename it and install the other?

---

I see other similar questions but in both they can really use the newest driver.

I know that it will be worse than using the GTX 970 alone but I still want to try. it.

Comment: What do you hope to achieve by using your GTX 280 alongside your GTX 970?

Comment: @Ramhound use it as dedicated card for PhysX

Comment: Your generation gap is just to far.  Your 970 would do a better job doing the PhysX.

Comment: I thought it but I wanted to test by myself.

Comment: Unfortunately, what you wish seems impossible unless you have some guru-level programming and OS knowledge. The GTX 970 driver only supports back to the 400 series. Basically nVidia would have to make a conscious effort to merge support of the 200 series into the current driver. I would imagine it would also increase the driver size to over 600 MB. Good luck in your quest but overall I too think that the PhysX delivered by the 280 will actually hold back your 970

Comment: There was a video I saw of a GTX 480 using a 9800 GT for PhysX and the FPS drop was substantial vs. just running everything on the 480. I cannot find it though :(

Comment: Here is a solid run-down: http://www.volnapc.com/all-posts/how-much-difference-does-a-dedicated-physx-card-make and this picture specifically http://www.volnapc.com/uploads/3/0/9/1/30918989/7654086_orig.jpg unfortunately the blog does mention using a 200 series with 900 series so I question the credibility

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I think that you are right. Maybe you want to put your comments as an answer as I think it will be the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you wish seems impossible unless you have some guru-level programming and OS knowledge. The GTX 970 driver only supports back to the 400 series. Basically nVidia would have to make a conscious effort to merge support of the 200 series into the current driver. I would imagine it would also increase the driver size to over 600 MB. Good luck in your quest but overall I too think that the PhysX delivered by the 280 will actually hold back your 970

There was a video I saw of a GTX 580 using a 8600 GTS for PhysX and the FPS drop was substantial vs. just running everything on the 580. I cannot find it though :(

^ I found the video! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cbww3dhzK0M the details

Here is a solid run-down: http://www.volnapc.com/all-posts/how-much-difference-does-a-dedicated-physx-card-make and this picture specifically http://www.volnapc.com/uploads/3/0/9/1/30918989/7654086_orig.jpg. Unfortunately the blog does mention using a 200 series with 900 series so I question the credibility.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unless your cpu is very old, it would do a better job than the 280 for a few reasons:

1. The 280's hardware acceleration is for PhysX from its time, not modern PhysX
2. The 280 is very old hardware, so it is simply less powerful

Thus, unless you want to do 280-era tasks, it is better to run PhysX on the 970 or your CPU.

In order to run a dedicated PhysX card, you would need to cards able to run SLI together. They are not able.

Comment: If you read the comments in my question, I already know that. Although it's worse I want to test it.